# How do I push an entirely new project to an existing git repository?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am working on a java game in intellij which I had been version controlling with git. I have now copied the source files into a new gradle project and want to push this new project to the same repository, and work with this project from now on. However, when I try to push the new project, it says I need to pull, but I cannot pull since it is a entirely different project.

Comment: Have you tried `-f` force pushing?

Comment: If you push your new project to an existing branch, your old project will be gone. No files, no history, no nothing. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I want all my history of the old project kept in git, but just to push the new folder in the next commit... is this not possible?

Comment: The answer is going to be entirely dependent on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to reuse the same repository for an entirely new project? Do you want the new project to exist alongside the existing project and share its history?

Comment: Why not just make a new remote repository? Costs you nothing.

Comment: I need to keep the repository because it's for a university project; they want to see all of our git activity in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface my answer with that I **don't** think it is a good idea what you are trying to do. It is better to start a new repository for a separate project. But even if, for whatever reason, you are restricted to a single repository, I would suggest maintaining both projects in different *branches*.

---

What you are asking is "overwriting" all of a project and replacing its content in a single commit. You can do that as follows:

1. Copy the `.git` folder of the existing project into your new project
2. Run `git add -u` to delete all deleted files (most likely 99% of your files) from the staging area and update changed files
3. Optional: Write a `.gitignore` file for your new repository
4. Run `git add .` to add all new files to the staging area
5. `git commit` to write a new commit which only contains your new project files

Note that the diff of this commit will be huge (all old files deleted, all new files added), it will be basically useless. Switching between this commit and older commits can take a long time.

Any existing branches that you had cannot be merged back into your main branch after this procedure.